# How to add color bar for measuring cluster purity in R?

Tags: r

I am doing hierarchical clustering and I have ground truth of the data labels.
I would like to add color side bar such that shows the cluster purity (how many percentage of this cluster belongs to samples from class A, class B)
I would be happy to get your responses on it.

Here is what I mean:
    dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars)))

```
# Create a vector giving a color for each car to which company it belongs to
car_type <- rep("Other", length(rownames(mtcars)))
is_x <- grepl("Merc", rownames(mtcars))
car_type[is_x] <- "Mercedes"
is_x <- grepl("Mazda", rownames(mtcars))
car_type[is_x] <- "Mazda"
is_x <- grepl("Toyota", rownames(mtcars))
car_type[is_x] <- "Toyota"
car_type <- factor(car_type)
n_car_types <- length(unique(car_type))
cols_4 <- colorspace::rainbow_hcl(n_car_types, c = 70, l  = 50)
col_car_type <- cols_4[car_type]
plot(dend)
# extra: showing the various clusters cuts 
k234 <- cutree(dend, k = 2:4)
```